# Queries with different types of like

Tags: regex, mongodb, express

please I need this query 'select product where name 'prod%' from productos' but with node and mongo db, now I have this:

```
query["$or"].push({'product': new RegExp(cadsrch, 'i')});
```

This would do this -> '%prod%', but I need 'prod%'.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like that:

```
query["$or"].push({'product': new RegExp('^'+cadsrch, 'i')});
```

The prefix `^` says: *from the beginning of the string*.

Comment: @AlexanderCeballos What do you mean by did not work? If it didn't find any results was it supposed to? Can you give an example?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to leave out the / delimeters

Comment: Exactly, that query didn't find any results

Comment: @AlexanderCeballos Did you try without the `/` as Derick mentions?

Comment: like this? -> query["$or"].push({'contenidocompleto': '/^' + new RegExp(cadsrch, 'i')+ '/'});